# Concatenate the String values of all Maps in a List

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to adapt Lambda features, however few struggles here and there.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new LinkedList<>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("data1", "12345");
map.put("data2", "45678");
list.add(map);
```

I just want to print the values in comma separated format like `12345,45678`

So here goes my trial

```
list.stream().map(Map::values).collect(Collectors.toList()) //Collectors.joining(",")
```

and the output is `[[12345,45678]]`. It means, there's a list and inside list it's creating the comma separated value at `0` index. I do understand why it's doing though.

But I didn't get through how to extract my desired result unless I call `.get(0)` in the end of that expression.

Any help/some more insights on how to use lambdas better will be helpful

Comment: Why not use `Collectors.joining` as you have shown in your commented code?

Comment: Why do you have a `List<Map,String, String>>`? Do you want to add the _values_ of the `Map` to the `List`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, to be open i am doing lot more on the list. Just thinking, how to extract the values from nested collections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
list.stream()    
    .map(Map::values)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

The `flatMap` method flattens out a `Collection<Stream<String>>` into a single `Stream<String>`.

Alternatively, you can try what @Holger suggested in the comments.

Note that since you are using a `Map`, there is no guarantee that the order will be preserved. You might see the output as `45678,12345` at your end. If you wish to preserve the order, you can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Of course, you can also use `list.stream().flatMap(map ->map.values().stream()) …` instead of `list.stream().map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream) …`…

Comment: @Holger Sure. The idea of the answer was to keep the answer as close to the OP's attempt as possible. That being said, any specific advantage of using your option or are the two options semantically the same?

Comment: It’s a few characters shorter ;^). Well, lambda expressions are easier to debug and some people think, they are more readable than method references (and when comparing a single lambda with an alternative requiring multiple method references I tend to agree) and there are some minor differences in performance and memory consumption which are likely to be equalized by HotSpot, if they ever become relevant. But these options are semantically the same.

Comment: @Holger The sources I have been reading from always emphasized (indirectly) that method references make the code more readable. But I appreciate the explanation and your point of view as it shows the other side of the story.