# Java: get List of entries from Lists nested in HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `HashMap<Foo, ArrayList<Bar>> map` with the following structure:

```
|-- a
|   |-- a1
|   |-- a2
|   `-- a3
|
`-- b
    |-- b1
    |-- b2
    `-- b3
```

where `a` and `b` are objects of the type `Foo` and `a1`, `a2`, etc. objects of the type `Bar`.

What I want to have is a `List<Bar>` with the following structure:

```
|-- a1
|-- a2
|-- a3
|-- b1
|-- b2
`-- b3
```

Right now I have this code:

```
ArrayList<Bar> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
map.values().forEach(tempList::addAll);
return tempList;
```

But this feels a bit clumsy and inelegant.
How can I achieve this using the standard Java API, preferably with `java.util.Stream` (or lambda expressions)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056919/concatenate-the-string-values-of-all-maps-in-a-list or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682522/convert-mapstring-navigablemaplong-collectionstring-to-liststring-usin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Bar> bars = map.values()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```